# Fold children paths

Tags: python, data-structures

This is a more general programming/paradigm/algorithm question but I will lay it out using python.

Given the following data structure:

- a is a Element of type T
- a has a enumerable property called children with elements of type T

How do I fold this data structure to get all the paths from a start element?

To illustrate the problem further, let me elaborate

```
c = {
'children': []
}
b = {
'children': [c]
}
a = {
'children': [b]
}

fold_from_start(a) => [[a, b, c]]
```

This function should calculate all the paths from a. If we extend the previous like so:

```
d = {
'children': []
}
b['children'] = [c, d]

fold_from_start(a) => [[a, b, c], [a, b, d]]
```

So far I have come up with the following code using recursive construction:

```
def fold_from_start(start, path, paths):
    if not len(start['children']):
        paths.append(path)  # leaf element
    else:
        new_path = path.copy()
        new_path.append(start)
        for child in start['children']:
            fold_from_start(child, new_path, paths)
```

which can be called like this:

```
paths = []
fold_from_start(a, [a], paths)
```

Unfortunately it yields

```
[a, a, b]
[a, a, b]
```

I know I did see this code before in a textbook but unfortunately I cannot come up with how it is done.
What is the obvious issue in this function that I tend to overlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It were only a few small mistakes. This works:

```
c = {
'name' : 'c',
'children': []
}
b = {
'name' : 'b',
'children': [c]
}
a = {
'name' : 'a',
'children': [b]
}
d = {
'name' : 'd',
'children': []
}
b['children'] = [c, d]

def fold_from_start(start, path, paths):
    new_path = path.copy()
    new_path.append(start['name'])
    if len(start['children']) == 0:
        paths.append(new_path)  # leaf element
    else:
        for child in start['children']:
            fold_from_start(child, new_path, paths)

paths=[]
fold_from_start(a, [], paths)
print(str(paths))
```

You'll have to add the leaf node to the current path too.
But since you don't want to add it to the path variable of the caller, you copy first.